# How to remove get a substring after certain character that is repeated

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
var data = '
    6@[some data]
    8@[some other data]
    1@[more data]';
```

The data inside the brackets consists of numbers. For example, `4@[2019]`.
How do i remove the 6@, 8@ and 1@?
I tried to use split method but it is not working as it should.

```
let result = data.split('@')[1];
```

but result is

```
[some data]8
```

I would like the result to be

```
[some data][some other data][more data]
```

Comment: you meant data as object ? if yes than it's not a valid object, if as a string than you're missing quotes around, so please update question

Comment: is this better?

Answer (score 1):

Update if the pattern is always `digit followed by @` than you can use

```
 ^\d[^@]*@
```

---

You can use this pattern and replace

```
^\d[^\[]+|\n
```

```js
let str = `6@[some data]
8@[some other data]
1@[more data]
1@[some 1234]`
    
let final = str.replace(/^\d[^\[]+|\n/gm,'')
console.log(final)
```

Comment: thats just giving me[[[[[[[[[[

Comment: @veronika you show me what string input you have used ?

Comment: I downvoted because your answer did nothing to help OP. They simply want the [number]@ removerd.

Comment: down voter? Im sorry are you talking to me? I didnt downvote anything. I am new to javascript and just trying to understand some things. the data in the brackets are quite big but they are numbers, if thats what you were asking

Comment: @veronika is the pattern you want to remove is always `digits followed by @` ?

Comment: @liakoyras yeah you have a valid point, if the pattern is always `digit followed by @` than it's better to use `\d+[^@]+@`

Comment: @liakoyras I didnt realise it matters what is in the brackets. can you tell me what regex to use if the data in brackets are numbers? thanks for you answer

Comment: the regex in my answer works fine if there are no @ in the brackets.

Comment: @veronika it's not about what is inside brackets, i am asking about pattern you want to replace

Comment: ok ill just create a new question, as the solution you gave me works fine only with alphabet in brackets, not for numbers. this is the data 6@[2020]
8@[2010]
1@[7020]

Comment: @CodeManiac at first I had not considered your point of view at all, that's why I downvoted. But considering that the data in brackets consists of numbers, this answer is false after all.

Comment: @liakoyras no it's not false, thing is since your pattern is always at start so you need to use `^` anchor, see the update

Comment: the pattern is not always at start. The data is a single string.

Comment: @liakoyras it's no where mentioned it is not at start, from example it seems a pattern, i asked op and example provided in comment also has the same pattern, try your answer with input `1@[123@]`

Comment: Good one. However, there won't be a problem if the data inside the brackets does not contain any @

Answer (score 1):

This regex will find @ preceded by a number

```
/[0-9]+@/g
```

Use it like this:

```
let str = `6@[some data]
8@[some other data]
1@[more data]`

let final = str.replace(/[0-9]+@/g,'')
console.log(final)
```

This works fine if there are no @ in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to remove and/or replace pieces of text.  For example, the regexp `[0-9]+@` matches [one or more digits followed by an `@` sign](https://regexper.com/#%5B0-9%5D%2B%40), so you can remove all substrings matching that pattern from your data like this:

```js
var data = `
    6@[some data]
    8@[some other data]
    1@[more data]`;

data = data.replace( /[0-9]+@/g, '' );
console.log( data );
```

But what you probably *really* want to do is first parse your data into an array, e.g. like this:

```js
var data = `
    6@[some data]
    8@[some other data]
    1@[more data]`;

var array = data.split('\n').map( line => line.trim() ).filter( line => line.length > 0 );
console.log( array );
```

(The code above will split the `data` string into an array of lines, trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line and finally filter out any empty lines.  You may want to adjust that depending on the exact format of your actual input data.)

Then you can more easily process each line one by one.  For example, to split each line on `@` signs and extract only the portion after the first `@`, you could simply do:

```js
var data = `
    6@[some data]
    8@[some other data]
    1@[more data]`;

var array = data.split('\n').map( line => line.trim() ).filter( line => line.length > 0 );

var modified = array.map( line => line.split('@')[1] );
console.log( modified );
```

Of course, you can also use regular expressions on each line in the array, too.  For example, this will remove numbers followed by an `@` sign from the beginning of each string in the array, but leave any other `@` signs intact:

```js
var data = `
    6@[some data]
    8@[some other data]
    1@[more data]`;

var array = data.split('\n').map( line => line.trim() ).filter( line => line.length > 0 );

var modified = array.map( line => line.replace(/^[0-9]+@/, '') );
console.log( modified );
```